# OpenAM Membership module does not notify admin of new inactive accounts

Tags: openam

I am using OpenAM to authenticate users and OpenDJ as the user directory.  I have enabled the membership module that allows users to self register, but I have not found any way to notify the admin that a new account needs to be approved.

This seems like something that would just be a matter of entering an admin email and configuring smtp, but I have not found anywhere to enter an email address to receive these notifications.  Though I have been able to send "password reset" emails so smtp is working at least.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a built-in feature in the Membership module. If you want to have this feature you'll have to implement it yourself based on the Membership module. See https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Write+a+custom+authentication+module for details.